# alter paths for boost libs in Blender's CMake to use my system boost

Tags: python, scripting

i need help on how to alter blenders cmake to use my system boost instead of the one it dowloaded by itself. It automatically dose it for python, to us the same python I'm using on my computer. I believe this is pretty simple to do, but i have no idea on how to do it.

the reason for this, is that there is a library I'm trying to run in blender and it makes its own bindings with the boost it is made with. and so i can import DLIB into blender, but i cannot use any of the advance features. From going around the web, the only way for it to work properly in blender is for dlib to be compiled with blenders boost, which i believe is much harder to do, or for blender to be compiled with dlibs boost, which is what I'm going for.

So how do you do this?

thanks pascal

Comment: this is a question and answer forum. if the answer worked for you, click on accept. otherwise add a comment, why it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it is strange it downloaded boost.

If you are looking to change the CMake file, then go to line

```
find_package(Boost bla bla COMPONENTS ${__boost_packages})
```

Before that line, insert:

```
SET(BOOST_ROOT "path/to/boost/")
SET(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS YES)
```

With this, it should look for boost only in the specified BOOST_ROOT directory. You might need to move these commands to the upper-most levels of the if's.